# Prove (p → ¬q) is equivalent to ¬(p ∧ q)

Tags: proof-techniques, propositional-logic, natural-deduction

I need to prove the above sequent using natural deduction. I did the first half already i.e. I proved $(p\rightarrow\neg q)\rightarrow \neg (p \wedge q)$, but I'm stuck on where to start for the reverse i.e. proving $\neg (p \wedge q) \rightarrow (p\rightarrow\neg q)$. I figured I would start by assuming $\neg (p \rightarrow \neg q)$ and then working towards a contradiction, but I'm still at a dead end. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Hint 1: what exact contradiction do you come up with when you evaluate $\neg (p \rightarrow \neg q)$? Hint 2: The [contrapositive](https://www.csm.ornl.gov/~sheldon/ds/sec1.2.html) is your friend a lot of times with natural deduction. Give these a try and let us know what you come up with.

Comment: Hint 3: try to apply the techniques you applied proving the other direction of the conditional. Hint 4: try simplifying the expression to be proved by maybe removing terms or changing operators while still coming up with a correct valid expression. Then apply the proof techniques from the simpler problem to the hard one.

Comment: If nothing helps there is [this](http://teachinglogic.liglab.fr/DN/index.php) neat online tool for helping you to prove intermediate steps.

Comment: @ShyPerson thanks so much! Hints 1 + 3 did the trick :)

Comment: @plshelp that's a great resource! definitely bookmarking for later on

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Would be useful to tell us how you proved the "implies" part.

Answer (score 0):

Can we use that $a \to b$ is same as $\neg a \lor b$? If yes then:
$$\neg (p \wedge q) \rightarrow (p\rightarrow\neg q) $$
is same as
$$(\neg p \lor \neg p) \rightarrow (\neg p \lor \neg q)
$$

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, note that $\neg p$ means $p \rightarrow \hbox{False}$. (In some logics, this is the definition of negation.)

Therefore $\neg (p \wedge q) \leftrightarrow (p \rightarrow \neg q)$ means:
$$\left( \left(p \wedge q\right) \rightarrow \hbox{False} \right)\leftrightarrow \left(p \rightarrow q \rightarrow \hbox{False}\right)$$

This is just [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is this:

LHS

We already know that

(→¬) = (¬ + ¬)

RHS

By demorgan's law,

¬(∧) = (¬ + ¬)

Since LHS and RHS are same, so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof tree in natural deduction of the wanted implication, using $\Gamma = \{\neg(p\land q), p , q\}$:

$$\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{}{\Gamma\vdash p}\text{ax} \quad \dfrac{}{\Gamma\vdash q}\text{ax}
}{\Gamma\vdash p\land q}\land_i \quad\dfrac{}{\Gamma\vdash \neg(p\land q)}\text{ax}
}{\Gamma\vdash \bot}\neg_e
}{\neg(p\land q), p\vdash \neg q}\neg_i
}{\neg(p\land q)\vdash p\rightarrow \neg q}\rightarrow_i
}{\vdash \neg(p\land q)\rightarrow (p \rightarrow \neg q)}\rightarrow_i$$

Sorry the layout is a bit ugly without appropriate LaTeX packages.